# WinAPI SetCursorPos seems like not working properly on multiple monitors with different resolutions

Tags: c#

Im trying to adjust the mouse position to the center of a target window position. To do so, I precalculate the X and Y coordinates that leads to the center position. To perform the mouse move, I am using "SetCursorPos" method from the winapi. My issue is now that the function does not align the x value properly if the cursor is at a lower resolution display (Full HD) and the move has to be performed to a higher resolution display (UHD).

I found out that it performs the action correctly if the Y value is in the range of the window center position Y value.

When the Y value is higher or lower than the allowed Y range (1080), the X of the cursor will be set to the left edge (x = 0) of the target monitor, which means that the cursor is shown now on the correct display with the correct Mouse Y Position but with a wrong Mouse X Position.

[image]

I came up with the idea to execute the SetCursorPos method a second time which leads to success. I guess on the first time, the method considers the Y value range of the monitor where the mouse originally comes from. On second time the cursor is already displayed on the higher resolution monitor which forces the method to use the Y range of it.

Anyone got a better idea how to bypass this issue?

Comment: Forgot to post the link: https://imgur.com/a/H18LPOL

Comment: even if i have dpiAwae enabled it still doesnt work ;-/

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65519784/why-does-setcursorpos-reset-the-cursor-position-to-the-left-hand-side-of-the-dis

Comment: Btw have you found a solution to this?