# Why does SetCursorPos reset the cursor position to the left-hand side of the display?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouseevent

[`SetCursorPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos) moves the cursor to the specified screen coordinates. However, it seems to have a bug: if the cursor is moved from the main display onto a second display, and the new Y-coordinate is outside the Y-range of the main display, **the cursor's X-coordinate is reset to the left-hand side of the second display!** The bug is illustrated in the following diagram:

[image: SetCursorPos bug]

Here I have main display 1 on the left, and secondary display 2 on the right. Three examples of using `SetCursorPos` are shown, where a cursor is moved from main display 1 to secondary display 2.

In example `b`, `SetCursorPos` works as expected. However, in examples `a` and `c`, we try to move the cursor into a *bug area* of display 2, shown shaded red. **Then the cursor position is reset to the left-hand side of display 2 (shown shaded yellow)!**

Here is the shortest program that reproduces the bug:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
int main() {
    POINT origPoint;
    GetCursorPos(&origPoint);
    SetCursorPos(origPoint.x + 200, origPoint.y + 200);
}
```

This program moves the cursor diagonally down and to the right by 200 screen coordinates. Use it in the manner of example `c` in the diagram: put your cursor in the bottom-right of display 1, then run the program. You will find that the cursor is moved to the left-hand side of display 2.

Some notes:

- A workaround for this bug is to call `SetCursorPos` twice. The first call at least moves the cursor to the correct display. On the second call, the bug doesn't happen, because it's not moving across displays. However, in my case, I don't have easy access to change the site where this is called.
- I'm aware of [`ClipCursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clipcursor), but this is not the cause of the behavior. `GetClipCursor` reports a rect which contains the entire virtual screen (as reported by `GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)` etc). And even with `ClipCursor(NULL)`, the bug still happens. Also, the double-call workaround above disproves this hypothesis.
- `SetCursorPos` claims to succeed (returns `1`), whether it exhibits this bug or not. (Omitted error-checking above for brevity.)
- An alternative to `SetCursorPos` is [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput), passing a [`MOUSEINPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-mouseinput) containing "normalized absolute coordinates". But this method is also affected by the exact same bug!
- Another alternative to `SetCursorPos` is [`mouse_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event), passing normalized absolute coordinates. This method is also affected by the exact same bug!
- I'm running Windows 10, Version 20H2, Build 19042.085.

**Are there flaws in my mental model? Are there additional cursor movement restrictions or special cases that I am not aware of? Or should I report this as a Windows bug?**

Comment: Have you tried to called GetClipCursor before calling SetCursorPos (with error checking)?

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier. Yep. It gives me a clip rect that contains the entire virtual screen (i.e. large enough for the cursor to never get clipped). Also, calling `SetCursorPos` twice results in correct behavior (if the problem was caused by a clip rect, it should clip both calls to `SetCursorPos`). Also yes, `SetCursorPos` and `GetCursorPos` claim to succeed (error-checking omitted above for brevity). Will update with these comments.

Comment: Do both monitors have the same DPI?

Comment: The monitors have different DPIs reported by `GetDpiForMonitor`. My process is `PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE`. However, the bug seems to happen regardless of DPI differences, DPI awareness, and scaling factors!

Comment: Is the cursor in the applications client area?  Is the input desktop the current desktop?  (Probably "yes" to both of those, otherwise I'd have expected an error to have been returned.)

Comment: The reason is that screens with different resolutions will directly generate virtual walls, which will prevent the cursor from moving to another screen in the boundary area. When you use `SetCursorPos` to exceed the resolution of the current screen, the position where the cursor moves to another screen is actually the same as the boundary coordinates of the original screen.You can refer to the link for more infomation:[Mouse cursor on multiple screens with different PPI](https://superuser.com/questions/1051269/mouse-cursor-on-multiple-screens-with-different-ppi/1301681#1301681)

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT so `SetCursorPos`, rather than "teleporting" the cursor, is simulating linear movement, with collision detection? Interesting theory! Although this would suggest that movement in the other direction (e.g. reverse the arrow "c" in the diagram) would have the same issue, and would suggest that it wouldn't matter which display is main/primary. Neither of these seem to be true. I like the theory in general though - it's the best I've got!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @CesarVarela my eventual workaround was to call `SetCursorPos` twice. It's not pretty, but it seems to work.